# Extract XML text from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to extract values from XML in SQL Server. However if I try this query:

```
select 
    xmldata.query('(/entry/accounts/account/accountid/text())')
from 
    ltr_CPC_phx_acct_balance_XML
```

Short example of my XML:

```
<entry timestamp="2015-08-05T10:25:54">
    <accounts>
    <account><accountid>xxxx0800USD</accountid><balance>-100,02</balance></account>
    <account><accountid>xxxx2100EUR</accountid><balance>215,36</balance></account>
    <account><accountid>xxxx4301GBP</accountid><balance>96,54</balance></account>
    </accounts>
</entry>
```

Result:

```
1. xxxx0800USDxxxx2100EURxxxx4301GBP
```

Expected result should by something like this

```
1. xxxx0800USD
2. xxxx2100EUR
3. xxxx4301GBP
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to shred the XML by using [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx), something like :

```
select 
    accountid.value('.','varchar(100)') as accountid
from ltr_CPC_phx_acct_balance_XML
    OUTER APPLY xmldata.nodes('/entry/accounts/account/accountid') T(accountid)
```